# Express-jwt middleware typescript types issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to implement an express API that authenticates via a jwt token and I'm using the express-jwt middleware to authenticate access to a method:

```js
import express from 'express'
import jwt from 'express-jwt'

const app = express()

app.get('/protected', jwt({ secret: 'jwtSecret', algorithms: ['HS256'] }), prot)

const prot = (
    req: express.Request,
    res: express.Response,
    _next: express.NextFunction
): void => {
    res.json({
        msg: req.user,
    })
}

app.listen(3000)
```

But I get this error:

`Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.ts(2339)`

I've tried attaching `req: express.Request & { user: unknown }`, but then the function doesn't fit with express anymore.

Any ideas what I can do here. If worse comes to worse, can I just tell TypeScript to shut up somehow, since I know that the field will be there (even though I know that's not the point of TypeScript)

Comment: It would be nice to see an `ExpressJWTRequest` object exported from [`@types/express-jwt`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-jwt/index.d.ts) but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be anything for that :(

Comment: I realize this is several years later .. but if you check, as of ver. 7.4.2; you don't need the @types;

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b23a36e669fa127d1035e22ca93faab85b98e49f/notNeededPackages.json#L1616-L1619

Answer (score 1):

`user` is not an existing property on `req` object. You can make your own typings for `req` object by creating a `.d.ts` file on your project, for example, create a `express.d.ts` file and it will contains:

```
declare namespace Express {
   export interface Request {
       user: SomeType
   }
}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/OldlaceWhoppingComputationalscience

Try deleting the `express.d.ts` and the error will appears again.

Comment: If I make a type

`declare namespace ExpressJWT {
export interface JWTRequest extends express.Request {
user: unknown
}
}`

I get `(property) ExpressJWT.JWTRequest.user: unknown
Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`

Comment: I've already tried something similar and that did not work either

Comment: The name space is supposed to be `Express`, not `ExpressJWT`, have you tried mine? Check my repl.it

Answer (score 0):

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      user?: UserPayload;
    }
  }
}
```

this is an example of UserPaylaod

```
  interface UserPayload {
     id: string;
     email: string;
   }
```